# Utilities library for printing bunch of different iterative data types

Tags: c++

Is there a way to print out c++ datatypes that can be iterated over (vector, unordered_map) using a templated function? Like find out what the type of the iterator is and then print out all of the values.

Thank you

Comment: Are you talking about an iterator in general? I don't get what you are quite asking. Iterators from STL are generic traversing, meaning you can traverse through different data structures such as vector, maps, sets, list, etc.

Comment: Take a look at most [standard algorithm functions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm). The ones handling ranges uses iterators, but they don't know where the iterators are coming from. For them an iterator is an iterator is an iterator... It doesn't matter if it comes from a vector or a list or even a plain C array.

Comment: Oh and don't forget about [range-based `for` loops](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) which can be used with type-deduction. E.g. `for (auto const &data : some_container) std::cout << data;`

Comment: Tbh thats a piece of functionality you are expected to create yourself from the components of the standard library. There are too many possible variations in how they could be printed and its very trivial to do, so the standard does not provide for this.

Comment: Are you looking to implement Iterator design pattern for your class? [iterator-pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterator_pattern)